# Vector checking not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string previous;
string current;

vector<string> dislikes(4);
dislikes [0] = "cat1";
dislikes [1] = "cat2";
dislikes [2] = "cat3";
dislikes [3] = "cat4";

while(cin >> current){

for(int i = 0; i<dislikes.size(); ++i){
    if(current==dislikes[i]){
    cout << "BLEEP ";}

    else if(i=4);
    {cout << current << " ";}
    };


    previous = current;
};
return 0;
};
```

It will only replace cat1 with bleep when it appears in a sentence but none of the others. I cannot figure out why and have been staring at it for ages.

Comment: You put in way to many `;` if you end a scope "{}" you don't have to type a ';' thus `{/*conde here*/};` doesn't need a ; look up in a C/C++ book when you need to append it.

Comment: To minimize such kind of bugs in you code I would suggest you to keep space in expression e.g. an expression `i=4` should be written as `i = 4`, so that its readable. similarly you should add space after `;` and `,`.  (also read: about [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions))

Comment: @hetepeperfan I sort of got carried away with fixing errors and ended up over doing it.

Comment: @ThePeskyWabbit learn about indentations, improve readability so that this kind of errors easily spot.

Comment: Tips: use `set` or `unordered_set` and their `find` method to improve computational complexity to O(log n) or O(1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
else if(i=4);
```

should be

```
else if(i==3)
```

So there were three problems on this line:

- Using `=` instead of `==`. `=` sets the value of something, so `i` will be set to `4` which will end the loop. Use `==` to *compare* values.
- The value you want to compare against is `3`, not `4` because the vector is only 4 long, and the loop index will only reach `4 - 1`.
- The `;` after the `else` is the body of the `else`, so the else will actually do nothing.

Comment: And if you don't get a warning about this, turn on the warnings. If you do get a warning and choose to ignore it, shame on you!